# Could disk encrypted with cryptsetup on Linux be read on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, disk-encryption

I need to encrypt my USB disk so it's accessible both in Ubuntu and Windows 7. I plan to use cryptsetup in linux and another one in Windows, if that's possible. Is it possible to use cryptsetup drives on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what wikipedia says:

> dm-crypt and LUKS encrypted disks can be accessed and used under MS
>   Windows using FreeOTFE, provided that the filesystem used is supported
>   by Windows (e.g. FAT/FAT32/NTFS).
>
> Encrypted Ext2, Ext3 and Ext4 filesystems are supported by use of
>   Ext2Fsd (all ext* versions) or Ext2 Installable File System for
>   Windows (ext2 and ext3 only) and with FreeOTFE
>
> Cryptsetup/LUKS and the required infrastructure have also been
>   implemented on the DragonFly BSD operating system.[6]

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt)